# Keep Google Client ID after domain has been changed

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

We have moved our site domain from `oldsite.od.ua` to `newsite.ua` (not between subdomains and principal .tld).

Google Analytics continues to collect the same GA property and views, but all GA Client IDs changed. I know about cross-domain tracking, but in my case users don't visit the old domain to go to the new one.

Is there a way to transfer old IDs to the new domain?
We don't use the User ID because we don't have any authorization on our site.

Comment: @Open SEO, thanks for the answear.
If I understood correctly, I should:
1. We need to add a php script to the _oldsite.od.ua_ that will send a 302 redirect to the _newsite.ua_.
This redirect should contain a google client id.
Like https://newsite.ua/special/ga.png?ccvalue=GA1.3.1218996493.1586263874

2. https://oldsite.od.ua/special/ga.png and https://newsite.ua/special/ga.png 
Are there an examples of same page at the old and new domain ? Or what are these entities?

Comment: 3. Can you help me to find an example of such a php request? And an example of php request, that will accept a redirect at _newsite.ua_  and extract cookies from it

Comment: Can you set your questions at the level of my answer ?

Comment: Sure. Already done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible, while a little tricky.
You need to read the user _ga cookie that exists on the old site and set it for the same browser on the new site
This is only possible through a special redirect, here is a sample flow:

Accessing to newsite.ua would include in the source of every page of the news site a reference to a resource like an image on https://oldsite.od.ua/special/ga.png

That call is a pretext to allow reading the _ga cookie value on https://oldsite.od.ua/ for that browser through HTTP Request Headers
probably something like `GA1.3.1218996493.1586263874`

The request to ga.png would be handled by a PHP script for example, able to process HTTP Header values and it would do a **302 redirect** to

```
https://newsite.ua/special/ga.png?ccvalue=GA1.3.1218996493.1586263874
```

This allows to pass the value of the former GA cookie to the new site context. You will be able to access the "_ga" cookie value in PHP with something like

```
$_COOKIE["_ga"]
```

The HTTP Response to the call to https://newsite.ua/special/ga.png?ccvalue=GA1.3.1218996493.1586263874 would have an HTTP header like this

```
Set-Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1218996493.1586263874; Expires=<date in 13 months>
```

Thus passing through the value of the parameter as a cookie value. But only if the HTTP request to https://newsite.ua/ doesn't already holds a _ga in the Request Header (that would mean that the browser has already been migrated)

(You'll need to adjust the code to make sure it doesn't go into an infinite loop for example...)

Note that the "**.3.**" at the beginning of the initial cookie value needs to be replaced by "**.2.**" to match the _ga cookie generation rule on the new domain (it is based on the number of dots in the domain name, and allows GA to select the appropriate cookie between a domain and a subdomain) because in your case you move between different domain patterns

This applies to the `analytics.js` version

The [GA debug extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) will help you verify that it's taken into account

You should also consider handling user consent regarding tags and so in that migration..

Comment: thanks for the answear. If I understood correctly, I should: 1. We need to add a php script to the oldsite.od.ua that will send a 302 redirect to the newsite.ua. This redirect should contain a google client id. Like newsite.ua/special/ga.png?ccvalue=GA1.3.1218996493.1586263874 2. oldsite.od.ua/special/ga.png and newsite.ua/special/ga.png Are there an examples of same page at the old and new domain ? Or what are these entities?

Comment: 3. Can you help me to find an example of such a php request? And an example of php request, that will accept a redirect at newsite.ua and extract cookies from it

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a PHP developer, and I didn't find a close example. But I know that Ad Networks keep doing similar scripts to propagates cookies across domains and allow cookie matching between their user bases

Comment: Thank you very much.